# Debug website that requires client certificates in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, cryptography, client-certificates

I have a website that is hosted using IIS7 when deployed, but we are seeing strange behavior with a web service we use that requires a client certificate. So what I'd like to do is debug our website locally to step through the code and take a closer look at the issue.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to have the website accept client certificates when I'm running it locally (debugging it). If I just run it locally and perform an operation on the website that uses my client cert, it is clearly not pulling it from the browser because I'm getting "m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle" errors.

Is there a way to have the website accept client certificates when running locally? I have IIS7 installed on the same machine that has Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed, and the OS is Windows 7.

Thanks.